# My question concerns a possible hierarchy of sets of integers with the property that their sum divides the sum of their cubes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Divide the sequence of consecutive positive integers as follows. The first block runs from $1$ to $b$, the second from $(2b+1)$ to $3b$, the third from $(4b+1)$ to $5b$, ..., the $(a+1)^{th}$ from
$(2ab+1)$ to $(2a+1)b, a≥0,b≥1.$

Choose for the content of the first block only the numbers $i,j,k,…$ , (at least one but possibly all $\space b\space$ of them), and, for the contents of all subsequent blocks, the integers in the corresponding positions in the sequence.

Conjecture:

If it is proved that, in the first block, $(i+j+k+⋯)$ divides $(i^3+j^3+k^3+⋯)$, then this division property holds for the sequence of all (a+1) blocks.

The interest in the problem is that, if true, one can use a set of blocks as a block of higher order,and proceed recursively.

Comment: Consider typesetting your equations in LaTeX. Essentially, you're claiming that if we have some integers $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ with $\sum_{i=1}^ka_i\mid \sum_{i=1}^ka_i^3$, then for any integer $m$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^k(a_i+m)\mid \sum_{i=1}^k(a_i+m)^3$, correct? (By picking i,j,k.. before we pick b, which I've renamed $m$)

Comment: Here is my attempt in LaTeX: I hope I get this right:

Comment: Here is my attempt in LaTeX: I hope I get this right: If \sum_{i=1}{i=k}{a_{i}} can be proved to divide \sum_{i=1}{i=k}{(a_{i})^3} then \sum_{j=0}{j=a}{\sum_{i=1}{i=k}{a_{i}+2jb}} divides \sum_{j=0}{j=a}{\sum_{i=1}{i=k}{(a_{i}+2jb)^3}}.

Comment: You have to put dollar signs around LaTeX expressions to get them to display nicely, and for sums you have to use the '^' to get the upper bound in the right place. For for example, for the first summation you want to write \sum_{i=1}^{i=k}. This gets you the following: "If $\sum_{i=1}^{i=k}{a_{i}}$ can be proved to divide $\sum_{i=1}^{i=k}{(a_{i})^3}$ then $\sum_{j=0}^{j=a}{\sum_{i=1}^{i=k}(a_{i}+2jb})$ divides $\sum_{j=0}^{j=a}{\sum_{i=1}^{i=k}{(a_{i}+2jb)^3}}$" However this isn't true. Try $k=3$, $a_1=1,a_2=2,a_3=3$ and $j=1,b=4$.

Comment: With your example, I'm dividing 36 into 3096, which gives me an integer quotient. The gaps of length b between the blocks of equal length seem to ensure that I don't get a factor 2 in the denominator which I can't cancel.

Comment: You're right, I made an arithmetic error. At least I understand the problem now, so that's good. Still have no idea how to solve it though. The double summation may be simplified by exchanging summations and applying a variant on Faulhaber's formula for exponent $3$, I think. That should get you a single summation of something quartic in the $a_i$.

Comment: I'll play with that idea: anything to simplify the expression.

Comment: Also, for $k=2$, the condition is always satisfied, because $a_1^3+a_2^3=(a_1+a_2)^3-3a_1a_2(a_1+a_2)$. For $k=3$ the condition is satisfied if and only if $a_1+a_2+a_3\mid a_1a_2a_3$.

Comment: I knew about k = 2, but not k = 3, so thank you for that.

Comment: I've now generalised Mastrem's result to all k > 2. I can reformulate the problem accordingly but unfortunately not solve it!

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comments, I think that you conjecture that if $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k}{a_{i}}\mid \sum_{i=1}^{k}{a_{i}^3}$, then $$\sum_{j=0}^{a}{\sum_{i=1}^{k}(a_{i}+2jb)}\mid \sum_{j=0}^{a}{\sum_{i=1}^{k}{(a_{i}+2jb)^3}}$$

Let
$$S:=\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i,\qquad T:=\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i^2,\qquad U:=\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i^3$$

Then, one has
$$\sum_{j=0}^{a}\sum_{i=1}^{k}(a_i+2jb)=\sum_{j=0}^{a}(S+2jbk)=(a+1)(S+kab)$$
and

$$\begin{align}&\sum_{j=0}^{a}\sum_{i=1}^{k}(a_i+2jb)^3
\\\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{a}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\bigg(a_i^3+6bja_i^2+12b^2j^2a_i+8b^3j^3\bigg)
\\\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{a}\bigg(U+6bTj+12b^2Sj^2+8b^3kj^3\bigg)
\\\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{a}U+6bT\sum_{j=0}^{a}j+12b^2S\sum_{j=0}^{a}j^2+8b^3k\sum_{j=0}^{a}j^3
\\\\&=(a+1)U+3a(a+1)bT+2a(a+1)(2a+1)b^2S+2b^3ka^2(a+1)^2
\\\\&=(a+1)\bigg(U+3abT+2a(2a+1)b^2S+2a^2(a+1)b^3k\bigg)
\\\\&=(a+1)\bigg(U+3abT+2a^2b^2S+2a(a+1)b^2\bigg(S+kab\bigg)\bigg)\end{align}$$

So, your conjecture can be simplified as

"If $S\mid U$, then $(S+kab)\mid (U+3abT+2a^2b^2S)$".

- For $k=1$, your conjecture is true since $U+3abT+2a^2b^2S=(S+ab)(2 a bS +S^2)$.
- For $k=2$, your conjecture is true since $U+3abT+2a^2b^2S=(S+2 a b) (a b S  +\frac{3T-S^2}{2})$.
- For odd $k\ (\geqslant 3)$, your conjecture is false. Take $a=1$, $b=\dfrac{(k-1)k(k^2-2k-1)}{2}$, $a_i=i\ (1\leqslant i\leqslant k-1)$, $ a_k=\dfrac{(k-1)k(k^2-2k-1)}{2}$ for which one has $$\frac{U}{S}=\frac 14 (k - 1) \bigg(k^6(k-5)+(k+1)( 5 k^4 - 3 k^2 -1\bigg)\in\mathbb Z$$and $$\begin{align}V:&=\frac{U+3abT+2a^2b^2S}{S+kab}
  \\\\&=\frac 12\bigg(3 k^7 - 21 k^6 + 55 k^5 - 74 k^4 + 78 k^3 - 98 k^2 + 130 k - 169\bigg)
  \\&\qquad\qquad+\frac{221 k - 509}{2(k^2 - k - 3)}\end{align}$$Here, suppose that $V$ is an integer. Then, $2V$ is an integer $\implies \dfrac{221 k - 509}{k^2 - k - 3}$ is an integer $\implies \dfrac{221 k - 509}{k^2 - k - 3}\ge 1\implies 3\leqslant k\leqslant 219$ for which $\dfrac{221 k - 509}{k^2 - k - 3}$ is not an integer, so $V$ is not an integer.
- For even $k\ (\geqslant 4)$, your conjecture is false. Take $a=1$, $b=\dfrac{(k-1)k(k^2-2)}{2}$, $a_i=i\ (1\leqslant i\leqslant k-1)$, $a_k=\dfrac{(k-1)k(k^2-2)}{2}$ for which one has
  $$\frac{U}{S}=\frac{1}{4}\bigg((k - 1)^2 k^2 (k^4 - 5 k^2 + 7)-k(k-2)\bigg)\in\mathbb Z$$ and $$V=\frac 12\bigg(3 k^7 - 9 k^6 + k^5 + 18 k^4 - 10 k^3 - 15 k^2 + 22 k -25\bigg)$$$$+\frac{41 k^2 - 31 k - 25}{2( k^3 +  k^2 - 2 k - 1)}$$ Here, suppose that $V$ is an integer. Then, $2V$ is an integer $\implies \dfrac{41 k^2 - 31 k - 25}{k^3 + k^2 - 2 k - 1}$ is an integer $\implies \dfrac{41 k^2 - 31 k - 25}{k^3 + k^2 - 2 k - 1}\ge 1\implies 4\leqslant k\leqslant 38$ for which $\dfrac{41 k^2 - 31 k - 25}{k^3 + k^2 - 2 k - 1}$ is not an integer, so $V$ is not an integer.

Comment: That simplification is really useful. But can you check your algebra beneath for U/S and V? Fitting your example, and choosing integer values 2, 4, 6, I get 24 for U/S and 72 for V.

Comment: @Paul Stephenson : What I wrote is that "For odd $k\ (\geqslant 3)$, your conjecture is false. Take $a=1$, $b=\frac{(k-1)k(k^2-2k-1)}{2}$, $a_i=i\ (1\leqslant i\leqslant k-1)$, $ a_k=\frac{(k-1)k(k^2-2k-1)}{2}$". So, if $k=3$, then $a=1,b=6,a_1=1,a_2=2,a_3=6$ is a counterexample to your conjecture that if $(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_k)$ is such that $S\mid U$, then for any $(a,b)$, $V$ is an integer. I'm not saying that if $k=3,a=1,b=6$, then for any $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ satisfying $S\mid U$, $V$ is not an integer.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.

Comment: Your finding chimes with another observation, derivable from dividing and examining remainders. For the case k = 3, for example, the sum of the integers must divide their product - so 1, 2, 6 fails, as you've proved in the general case . So we can put my (unqualified) conjecture to bed.

Comment: - meaning that the bonus has been claimed by math love.

Comment: @Paul Stephenson : "For the case $k = 3$, for example, the sum of the integers must divide their product - so $1, 2, 6$ fails, as you've proved in the general case." I'm not the person who said that in a comment. I found another counterexample $k=3,a=1,b=2,a_1=1,a_2=6,a_3=14$ satisfying $a_1+a_2+a_3\mid a_1a_2a_3$. I think that $S\mid U\iff a_1+a_2+a_3\mid \color{red}3a_1a_2a_3$.

Comment: I've posted a new version, generalising that fact, for you to look at.

Comment: (As you wrote, it's three times the product, sorry. This was originally noted by Mastrem.)